# Prevent CKEditor from removing html tags when removing text in text mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to set up CKEditor in such a way that I can edit text (remove/add) and all the existing html tags will remain in source code e.g. I would like to keep all html tags empty if I remove whole text in editing mode.

For example:
I have that text in text mode:

```
One two three
```

and it looks in source mode like below:

```
<span data-x="1.1">One </span><span data-x="8.9">two </span><span data-x="8.9">three </span><br />
```

After removing whole text I would like to preserve empty html elements like below:

```
<span data-x="1.1"></span><span data-x="8.9"></span><span data-x="8.9"></span><br />
```

My initial CKEditor configuration is here:

```
    CKEDITOR.config.height = 800;
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities_additional = '';
    CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;
    CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(*)';
    CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

Does anybody know if this is achivable?

Comment: It might be very tricky as natively browsers can remove those elements, what is independent from using CKEditor. Take a look into this sample: https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/BYjoyo. If you remove yellow span tis element will disappear from the DOM completely and this is done by browser directly not the editor. That's why it might be quite complicated task to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I noticed the same. The DOM elements are modified. I was wondering if it is possible to write some javascript functions which will disallow to remove some html tags. I am not sure if this is achievable